Cannot find 'AVURLAssetOverrideMIMETypeKey' in scope
I am using audioplayers package in my flutter app. It works well on android, but when i try to generate an archive for iOS, the build fails with the following message:
Cannot find 'AVURLAssetOverrideMIMETypeKey' in scope
and the cuasing file is
 WrappedMediaPlayer inside the audioplayers> audioplayers_darwin
I have been looking around for any solution but no luck so far.

I encountered this issue a few days ago, and here’s some information that might help.
This problem seems to be due to Apple's restrictions on Xcode. You need Xcode version 15 or higher to use the audioPlayers package.
An issue has been opened on the audioplayers GitHub repository:
GitHub Issue

AVURLAssetOverrideMIMETypeKey is available in iOS 17, that's mean you need iOS 17 SDK. iOS 17 SDK is provided with Xcode 15
